# Web Based 2D Game - Which engine?

Tags: java, browser

I'd like to develop a web based 2d game, similar to flashgames.

It should supports Sprites etc., so that it's really easy to do the graphic stuff. I don't have flash, so are there any reliable (JavaScript) engines maybe, with active Users?

...Or could I use Java instead, build an offline game and afterwards, make it playable in a webbrowser with a certain plugin? That would be really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good 2D library in JavaScript is http://gamejs.org (I'm the main dev) - it supports sprites, collisions, etc.

If you are already familiar with Flash ('similar to flashgames'?) then you might want to try http://easeljs.com

Finally, here's a pretty complete but probably overwhelmingly long list of JavaScript game engines: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Java would a Java Applet be the technology you are searching for.
I dont think that JavaScript would be a good choice as soon as it gets a bit more graphic intense

Comment: That's true... I noticed that yesterday :/